# Сохранить выбранный combobox после закрытия окна

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Написал программу с использованием MVVM, WPF. У меня получилось написать такой код во вью и так он работает.

```
private void ThisWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cmbView.SelectedIndex = Properties.Settings.Default.saveComboBox;
        txtHeight.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Height;
        txtWidth.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Width;
    }        

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.saveComboBox = cmbView.SelectedIndex;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Height = txtHeight.Text;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Width = txtWidth.Text;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

Но по принципу паттерна MVVM нельзя ничего писать во вью. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить эту проблему. У меня есть combobox и 2 textbox, в которых отображается информация о выбранном объекте. И есть 2 кнопки, сохранить и отменить. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы при новом открытии формы отображались новые данные придерживаясь паттерна MVVM

Comment: Сохраняйте состояние VM при закрытии окна и восстанавливайте при открытии.

Comment: @tym32167 для этого нужно использовать сериализацию?

Comment: можно, но не обязательно.

Comment: @tym32167 я хотел уточнить, а как именно я могу сохранить состояние VM? я пытался сейчас найти в интернете пример, но ничего не нашел, не могу понять как именно это нужно реализовать

Comment: Ну я бы написал свой класс, типа MySettings, в этом класе бы указал все поля, что хочу сохранить, сделал бы 2 метода во VM - один на записть класса куда нибудь (любым способом), второй на чтение класса. Ну и при закртытии окна вызывал метод на запись, чтобы записать всё, что зочу сохранить, при открытии - на чтение, чтобы считать что было сохранено и настроить VM в соотвествии с этим.